# GOST cipher test vectors

Tags: cryptography, cryptanalysis

Does anyone know where to find test vectors for the GOST cipher? I have been looking around for quite some time, and have been unable to find anything. I know that the sboxes are dependent on the implementation, so hopefully the test vectors you know of has them too. the rfcs dont have anything

i have found [this](http://textop.us/Encryption/GOST), but there is no way to tell what sbox they used, short of reverse engineering it, so that website is not very helpful

Comment: What are you testing? If you are trying to break GOST see [Security Evaluation of GOST 28147-89 In View Of International Standardisation](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/211)

Comment: im just trying to get test vectors to see if my implementation works properly or to see if i can find where my implementation is failing

Answer (score 2):

The official specifications seem to lack of test vectors but there are libraries including some:

- Crypto++ Library http://www.cryptopp.com/
- Bouncycastle Library http://www.bouncycastle.org/ (in class `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.test.GOST28147Test`)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Digging into source code and reading it is not one of my skills :(

Comment: Maybe you can use these tested implementations to generate some test vectors.

Comment: would people answer (a new question) if i asked if my knowledge of how to implement gost is correct? I dont want people complaining about me asking about the same thing over and over again

Comment: @calccrypto, I dont think anybody would object on grounds of it being a duplicate of this one, but I think there may be other issues at play here. For one, unless you are a professional cryptographer, you shouldn't be implementing this on your own. If you are, then you should probably be able to infer from the RFC or whatever. If you're just doing this to learn, then I think your question would probably be too broad... In general, I would say if you have a specific difficulty, or questionable point, go for it - otherwise, you could also try over in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

```
orginal: 00000000 00000000
key   : 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
1. cevrim ciktisi: 00000000 bb268a72
2. cevrim ciktisi: bb268a72 ca44ee08
3. cevrim ciktisi: ca44ee08 bed841b7
4. cevrim ciktisi: bed841b7 b89f4820
5. cevrim ciktisi: b89f4820 24424fa0
6. cevrim ciktisi: 24424fa0 ea684495
7. cevrim ciktisi: ea684495 56ff7562
8. cevrim ciktisi: 56ff7562 767aa8e8
9. cevrim ciktisi: 767aa8e8 62663a1b
10. cevrim ciktisi: 62663a1b 3ebf58ca
11. cevrim ciktisi: 3ebf58ca fdfd2330
12. cevrim ciktisi: fdfd2330 ad3fd177
13. cevrim ciktisi: ad3fd177 6421838e
14. cevrim ciktisi: 6421838e 473f9147
15. cevrim ciktisi: 473f9147 f9782558
16. cevrim ciktisi: f9782558 34a858de
17. cevrim ciktisi: 34a858de 8ee4646e
18. cevrim ciktisi: 8ee4646e b2129bf2
19. cevrim ciktisi: b2129bf2 dbca0a4a
20. cevrim ciktisi: dbca0a4a 81530479
21. cevrim ciktisi: 81530479 50f69913
22. cevrim ciktisi: 50f69913 4c66800c
23. cevrim ciktisi: 4c66800c 1ad02f91
24. cevrim ciktisi: 1ad02f91 7793fd4c
25. cevrim ciktisi: 7793fd4c 93b198c6
26. cevrim ciktisi: 93b198c6 9a88a8af
27. cevrim ciktisi: 9a88a8af e72efd01
28. cevrim ciktisi: e72efd01 33ee527f
29. cevrim ciktisi: 33ee527f 48fa1c65
30. cevrim ciktisi: 48fa1c65 85a4ecea
31. cevrim ciktisi: 85a4ecea 4d33070b
32. cevrim ciktisi: 4d33070b 0eca1a54
encryted: 0eca1a54 4d33070b
```

Comment: with which sbox?